# Python3 indentation errors

Tags: python-3.x

```
for x in range(0, podCount):
    for resourcelimitdata in resourcelimityaml:
        get_resource_limits(resourcelimitdata, data["spec"]["template"]["spec"]["containers"][x]["name"])
        if "resources" not in data["spec"]["template"]["spec"]["containers"][x]:
            print("No resources key", file=sys.stderr)
        else:
        if "limits" not in data["spec"]["template"]["spec"]["containers"][x]["resources"]:
            print("No limits key", file=sys.stderr)
        else:
        if "cpu" not in data["spec"]["template"]["spec"]["containers"][x]["resources"]["limits"]:
            print("No limits.cpu key", file=sys.stderr)
        else:
            cpu_check("limits.cpu", data["spec"]["template"]["spec"]["containers"][x]["resources"]["limits"]["cpu"], limits_cpu)
        if "memory" not in data["spec"]["template"]["spec"]["containers"][x]["resources"]["limits"]:
            print("No limits.memory key", file=sys.stderr)
        else:
            memory_check("limits.memory", data["spec"]["template"]["spec"]["containers"][x]["resources"]["limits"]["memory"], limits_memory)
        if "requests" not in data["spec"]["template"]["spec"]["containers"][x]["resources"]:
            print("No requests key", file=sys.stderr)
        else:
        if "cpu" not in data["spec"]["template"]["spec"]["containers"][x]["resources"]["requests"]:
            print("No requests.limits key", file=sys.stderr)
        else:
            cpu_check("requests.cpu", data["spec"]["template"]["spec"]["containers"][x]["resources"]["requests"]["cpu"], requests_cpu)
        if "memory" not in data["spec"]["template"]["spec"]["containers"][x]["resources"]["requests"]:
            print("No requests.memory key", file=sys.stderr)
        else:
            memory_check("requests.memory", data["spec"]["template"]["spec"]["containers"][x]["resources"]["requests"]["memory"], requests_memory)
```

Comment: please format your code, ask a question and show the stack trace from your error, In its current form your question does not meet the criteria of stack overflow

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You will find here people ready to help, provided you respect the site rules. As a new user, you should read [ask] to know the way the community expects the questions to be presented. Your current one is a code only question et gives no explaination on the problem (even if the title gives some hints) and does not show the full error text/stacktrace, nor the line where the error occurs. Because of that it could be downvoted and get no answer.